# GXT Basic Grid do not display data after loading

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I have problem: my basic grid do not displays information after loading it from DB. Debugger shows me that data is selected from DB and in firebug I see that data is received in browser, but not displayed in grid. It only renders header of table. I spent a lot of time trying to understand what is wrong. Maybe your fresh view can help to solve this problem. The problem is somewhere here. Code of button that render table on click:

```
  Button users = new Button("Users", new SelectionListener<ButtonEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void componentSelected(ButtonEvent ce) {
            center.removeAll();

            final List<ColumnConfig> configs = new ArrayList<ColumnConfig>();
            configs.add(new ColumnConfig("id", "Id", 30));
            // and a few other columns

            RpcProxy<BaseListLoadResult<User>> proxy = new RpcProxy<BaseListLoadResult<User>>() {
                @Override
                protected void load(Object loadConfig, AsyncCallback<BaseListLoadResult<User>> callback) {
                    userServiceAsync.getUsers((BaseListLoadConfig) loadConfig, callback);
                }
            };
            // final BaseListLoader<ListLoadResult<User>> loader = new BaseListLoader<ListLoadResult<User>>(proxy, new BeanModelReader());
            final BaseListLoader<ListLoadResult<User>> loader = new BaseListLoader<ListLoadResult<User>>(proxy);
            ListStore<User> listStore = new ListStore<User>(loader);
            ColumnModel cm = new ColumnModel(configs);
            Grid<User> grid = new Grid<User>(listStore, cm);
            grid.setStripeRows(true);
            grid.addListener(Events.Attach, new Listener<ComponentEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handleEvent(ComponentEvent be) {
                    Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new Scheduler.ScheduledCommand() {
                        @Override
                        public void execute() {
                            loader.load(new BaseListLoadConfig());
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            center.add(grid);
            center.layout(true);
        }
    });
```

Verisons: GWT - 2.1.1 and GXT 2.2.5
Thanks for all your answers

Answer (score 0):

OMG! Solving is so simple... *facepalm*. I forgot to set size of grid. Just adding  grid.setHeight(300); to code solve this problem. Data is received, but not displaying because it has no place on page to render it. Do not repeat my stupid mistake